# Excel VBA code to populate cell with text adjacent to cell based on choice in adjacent

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Trying to write code to populate a cell adjacent to a cell with a drop-down menu, based on the choice made in the drop-down menu.

I need this to apply to only the active sheet and not necessarily needed for the whole workbook.

Relatively new to writing code in VBA and probably a rookie mistake, but still need some help!

Getting runt-time error **Method 'Value' of object 'Range' failed.**

Here's the code I have, and it's the only code in the whole workbook...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


Select Case Range("F18")

Case "Made Margin/Made Sales $"
    Worksheets("Store #").Range("G18").value = 
    "Made margin by $XXX GIG at XX.XX%. Shrink  at XX.XX% or $XXX. QTD Margin at 
    XX.XX%"

Case "Made Margin/Missed Sales $"
    Worksheets("Store #").Range("G18").value = 
    "Made margin by $XXX GIG at XX.XX%. Shrink at XX.XX% or $XXX. QTD Margin at XX.XX%   
    Missed sales by $XXX. Begin explaining Sales $ miss here"

Case "Missed Margin/Made Sales$"
    Worksheets("Store #").Range("G18").value = "Missed margin by $XXX GIG at XX.XX%.   
    Shrink at XX.XX% or $XXX. QTD Margin at XX.XX% Made sales by $XXX. Begin explaining   
    Margin $ miss here"

Case "Missed Margin/Missed Sales"
    Worksheets("Store #").Range("G18").value = "Missed margin by $XXX GIG at XX.XX%.  
    Shrink at XX.XX% or $XXX. QTD Margin at XX.XX% Begin explaining Margin $ miss here,  
    followed by explaining Sales $ miss"

End Select

End Sub
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Is "Store #" the sheet which contains this code? If yes, you should set `Application.EnableEvents=False` before you populate G18, otherwise you're going to re-trigger the Change event over and over.  Don't forget to set it back to `True` after the update.

Comment: That code wouldn't compile in its current form. Statements over multiple lines should use the `_` character to join the lines and strings over multiple lines should use `&` and `_` and appropriate double quotes - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg264411%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Tim- THANK YOU! The enable events saved the error message... now it only will return the first case, and if it is not the first case, it will return nothing... Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just have a VLOOKUP formula in G18 that looks up your message from a table?

Comment: If you're only matching the first case then maybe you have one or more typos in your code or cell values. Should work - try testing with simpler string values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a condition that only triggers the event when F18 is changed. That, and bring the string into one single line or use the "_" key to signal multi-lined code. I would also make sure there's only one set of quotes per case value or else that will mess up the code.

I tried this and the code worked great.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F18")) Is Nothing Then

Select Case Range("F18")

Case "Made Margin/Made Sales $"
    Worksheets("Store #").Range("G18").Value = "Made margin by $XXX GIG at XX.XX%.     Shrink  at XX.XX% or $XXX. QTD Margin at"

 Case "Made Margin/Missed Sales $"
    Worksheets("Store #").Range("G18").Value = "Made margin by $XXX GIG at XX.XX%. Shrink at XX.XX% or $XXX. QTD Margin at XX.XX%. Missed sales by $XXX. Begin explaining Sales $ miss here"

Case "Missed Margin/Made Sales$"
    Worksheets("Store #").Range("G18").Value = "Missed margin by $XXX GIG at XX.XX%. Shrink at XX.XX% or $XXX. QTD Margin at XX.XX% Made sales by $XXX. Begin explaining Margin $ miss here"

Case "Missed Margin/Missed Sales"
    Worksheets("Store #").Range("G18").Value = "Missed margin by $XXX GIG at XX.XX%. Shrink at XX.XX% or $XXX. QTD Margin at XX.XX% Begin explaining Margin $ miss here, followed by explaining Sales $ miss"

End Select

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I ran the code and it works, but I am running into the same problem... if the initial choice is not the first case, the code will not return any results at all. Any other selection than the first case only, the result is no returned results of any kind.

Comment: IfElse shouldn't make a difference. Hmm, Did you ensure that you turned application.events = true? Did you ensure that you only have one set of quotes per case value?

Comment: Yes.. APP events are true. Yes, the grammar is right on it... I just can't seem to figure this out. 

Is it a way that the Data Validation of the Drop-down decides what is changing the value of the cell?

Comment: Try changing it to "Select Case Range("F18").Value" - I know that sometimes this can cause some interesting behavior if left out.

Comment: Issun - Tried that and it didn't change the result... still won't continue past the first case... regardless of initial choice.

Comment: Before your `Select` statement, put up a message box with the value of F18: `MsgBox "I think F18 has this value: " & [F18].Value` . It might be instructive.  By the way, since your worksheet value changed I am assuming it is the active sheet so I didn't use Worksheets("Store #").Range("F18").Value - the `[F18]` is a handy shortcut for name of cell / range on active sheet.

Comment: Still getting the same result... this is very strange. I have updated the code to eric_s's code above, made various tweaks and tried some of the other suggestions and still am stuck with it not moving past the first case.

Comment: Can you post all the updated code, so we can take a look at where you're at now? That might help.

Comment: GOT IT!!!

Had a minor syntax issue that I discovered and now all runs as is supposed to!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please feel free to accept the answer by clicking the check mark under the up/down arrows on the answer. :)